# Javascript variable scope issues

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a list of markers for a map, which - when they are dragged onto the map (via jquery draggable) - the image is replaced with a map marker.

The problem I am having, is that when creating my marker controllers - they each have a specific type - extracted from a list. As I iterate through the list, each dragable element gets given its 'stop' function, which uses the variable 'type'... now when each element is dragged on - they all act as though they are the 'type' of the last element, rather than their own.

Can anyone suggest how I might restructure this so that each marker maintains its specific type?

```
var createMarkerControl = function(){       
   var markerTypes = ['custom', 'exit', 'food', 'medical', 'shelter', 'video'];
   var control = document.createElement('div');
   control.setAttribute('id', 'markerInput');

    for (var i = 0; i < markerTypes.length; i++){
       var image = document.createElement('img');
       image.setAttribute('id', 'draggable-' + markerTypes[i]);
       image.setAttribute('src', 'images/gui/' + markerTypes[i] + '.png');
       image.style.width = '30px';

       //Set type
       var type = markerTypes[i];

       //Make elements dragable/dropable                
       control.appendChild(image);

       $(image).draggable({
          helper: 'clone',
          stop: function(e){
             //Add marker to map
             var point = new google.maps.Point(e.pageX, e.pageY);
             customMap.addPlacemark(point, type);
          },
          cursorAt: {left: 15, top: 0}
       });


    }

    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER].push(control);
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use the `var` declaration inside a `for` loop, FYI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because JavaScript does not have block-level scope, only function-level scope.  The `image` and `type` variables are scoped to `createMarkerControl`, not to the loop.  More importantly, they are scoped **outside** your draggable closure, so every closure will share the `type` variable.

I think you want your inner loop to look more like this:

```
var createMarkerControl = function(){       
   var markerTypes = ['custom', 'exit', 'food', 'medical', 'shelter', 'video'];
   var control = document.createElement('div');
   control.setAttribute('id', 'markerInput');

   var createDraggable = function(image, type) {
       image.setAttribute('id', 'draggable-' + type);
       image.setAttribute('src', 'images/gui/' + type + '.png');
       image.style.width = '30px';

       //Make elements dragable/dropable                
       control.appendChild(image);

       $(image).draggable({
          helper: 'clone',
          stop: function(e){
             //Add marker to map
             var point = new google.maps.Point(e.pageX, e.pageY);
             customMap.addPlacemark(point, type);
          },
          cursorAt: {left: 15, top: 0}
       });
   };

    for (var i = 0; i < markerTypes.length; i++){
       var image = document.createElement('img');

       //Set type
       var type = markerTypes[i];

       createDraggable(image, type);

    }

    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER].push(control);
}
```

By placing the logic in a subfunction, you ensure that references to `type` and `image` are unique to the inner closures.

Comment: +1, but I would replace the calls to setAttribute with direct property access: e.g. `image.id = 'draggable-' + markerTypes[i];` as it's faster and less error prone (and less to type).

Comment: @RobG - already fixed!  I missed that in my copy-and-paste.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that `for` loops in JavaScript get their own variable scope (like they sometimes do in other languages), so the `type` variable you are defining is bound in the function's scope. So you really need another solid scope.

I personally would make a helper function that generated your `stop` closure for you. This will create a stable scope where your closure can live... Something like this:

```
var createMarkerControl = function(){       
   var markerTypes = ['custom', 'exit', 'food', 'medical', 'shelter', 'video'];
   var control = document.createElement('div');
   control.setAttribute('id', 'markerInput');

    for (var i = 0; i < markerTypes.length; i++){
       var image = document.createElement('img');
       image.setAttribute('id', 'draggable-' + markerTypes[i]);
       image.setAttribute('src', 'images/gui/' + markerTypes[i] + '.png');
       image.style.width = '30px';

       //Set type
       var type = markerTypes[i];

       //Make elements dragable/dropable                
       control.appendChild(image);

       $(image).draggable({
          helper: 'clone',
          stop: createStopper(type),
          cursorAt: {left: 15, top: 0}
       });


    }

    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER].push(control);
}


var createStopper = function(type) {
    return function(e){
        var point = new google.maps.Point(e.pageX, e.pageY);
        customMap.addPlacemark(point, type);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   $(image).data('type',type).draggable({
      helper: 'clone',
      stop: function(e){
         //Add marker to map
         var point = new google.maps.Point(e.pageX, e.pageY);
         customMap.addPlacemark(point, $(this).data('type'));
      },
      cursorAt: {left: 15, top: 0}
   });
```

In your code, `type` is overwritten each iteration in the `for` loop, but the value of `type` at any given iteration is never attached to the draggable image, but rather it's simply referenced in the `stop` callback. By the time `stop` is fired, the `type` value is on it's last assignment. The idea I provided above is to simply attach the value of `type` to the object so it can reference it from within itself on the callback.

Answer (score 0):

I know correct answers have been posted and they are good but a simple(IMHO) solution would just be to wrap the code you need in `(function(){ ... })();` so it creates a new scope.

```
var createMarkerControl = function(){       
    var markerTypes = ['custom', 'exit', 'food', 'medical', 'shelter', 'video'];
    var control = document.createElement('div');
    control.setAttribute('id', 'markerInput');

    for (var i = 0; i < markerTypes.length; i++)
    (function() {
       var image = document.createElement('img');
       image.setAttribute('id', 'draggable-' + markerTypes[i]);
       image.setAttribute('src', 'images/gui/' + markerTypes[i] + '.png');
       image.style.width = '30px';

       //Set type
       var type = markerTypes[i];

       //Make elements dragable/dropable                
       control.appendChild(image);

       $(image).draggable({
          helper: 'clone',
          stop: function(e){
             //Add marker to map
             var point = new google.maps.Point(e.pageX, e.pageY);
             customMap.addPlacemark(point, type);
          },
          cursorAt: {left: 15, top: 0}
       });


    })();

    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER].push(control);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xXkcG/2/